# Is there a way to get a list of all classes in an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone

I wonder if it is possible to see what classes an iPhone App is made of. I don't need the header or implementation contents, just the class names would be fine. Is otool my friend here, or are there better tools to find this out?

Answer (score 1):

otool is fine for what you want to accomplish, although its output can be pretty hard if you're looking for classes. I would suggest class-dump, which dumps out the headers for all classes in an iPhone App (and in effect the class list). The latest version of class-dump, 3.2, works with iPhone Apps.

http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/